# If/else Rails what to look for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, switch-statement

I cant figure out what parameters to select for comparison for the following scenario.

I want to link to a specific page on my site depending upon which scope is being used to grab the data being presented on my home page..Is this possible?

For example I have a posts and departments model, relationships as so

Post

```
belongs_to :department
```

Department

```
belongs_to :post
```

I grab the posts via a scope and then have a method to grab the first post from its scope.

```
scope :tynewydd_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Ty Newydd"}, :order => "posts.published_on DESC"
scope :woodside_posts, :include => :department, :conditions => {"departments.name" => "Woodside"}, :order => "posts.published_on DESC"
```

Then to show the first post from each

```
def self.top_posts
#Array with each of the 4 departments - first record
top_posts = [
  self.tynewydd_posts.first,
  self.woodside_posts.first,
  self.sandpiper_posts.first,
  self.outreach_posts.first
]
#remove entry if nil
top_posts.delete_if {|x| x==nil}
return top_posts
end
```

In my view then i iterate through the top posts

```
<% @toppost.each do |t| %>
<%= link_to 'Read more' %> <!-- Want to put a helper method here -->

<% end %>
```

Routes

```
/tynewyddnews #tynewydd_posts
/woodsidenews #woodside_posts
```

Within the @toppost instance variable i have the attribute department.name available, i access via t.department.name in my .each loop.

How would i go about saying "if @toppost.department.name == "xxxx" then link_to "/path" for example. just looking for some tips on structure or if this can be converted into a case statement then that would be even better

Thanks

Comment: so it's a 1:1 relationship?

Comment: hello again :), yes think i set it up correctly a post can only have one department and a department belongs_to a post

Comment: then correct it so one can have a `has_one` and other `belongs_to`, depending on where you want to store the foreign key. In this way (if it's even working) you store one extra foreign key.

Comment: can you show the routes where you would like to redirect and how the controller handles them?

Comment: im ok with that part on this one, its the syntax and comparison im a little stuck on, the if and == part, what to compare, you could just provide dummy routes

Comment: i couldn't because i don't know how your routes look like

Comment: updated, does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash instead of a array, and then only return the key's since you won't be needing their values:

```
def self.top_posts
   top_posts = { "tynewydd" => self.tynewydd_posts.first, 
              "woodside" => self.woodside_posts.first,
              "sandpiper" => self.sandpiper_posts.first,
              "outreach" => self.outreach_posts.first
               }
   top_posts.delete_if {|x| x.value==nil}
   return top_posts.keys
end
```

Now you are getting an array of the hash keys like this:
`["tynewydd","woodside",..]`

And in your view:

```
<% @toppost.each do |t| %>
      <%= link_to 'Read more', "#{t}news_path" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: apologies, so i dont need to do an if statement then? by using a hash i can just select the key and it will link to the appropriate route? what else would you like to see? thank you by the way

Comment: well do you want to show the results of the scopes on the page you are having all these links? But yeah, nevermind, this should work, try it out yourself..

Comment: the link will take me to the relevant page where all posts for that department are, that is enough for what i want to achieve in this scenario....by using a hash i can just select the key and it will link to the appropriate route?

Comment: can i pass a path as the key, so tynewyddnews_path for example?

Comment: yeah, i'm gonna modify it a little bit since you only need the keys

Comment: that's great, will try this later, thanks v much, didn't even realise you could do this, so this will return the correct key depending on which scope is being used? ie which link i click

Comment: No problem, tell me how it goes, just watch out how you made your routes

Comment: hi just wanted to ask a question, will return the correct key depending on which scope is being used? ie which link i click it will recognise which scope is being used?

Comment: it will return the path od the svopes that exist and you will implement on all of those paths the info to show

Comment: another question sorry, i notice that in your answer only the keys are being returned, so if i want to display attributes in the @toppost loop, ie t.comments, t.title then i can remove .keys from the end of return?

Comment: yes, i only returned the keys since you said "that is enough for what i want to achieve in this scenario". If you want to return everything remember that it's a hash and change the link to path to `"#{t.key}news_path"`

Comment: thanks for a very nice solution, learned a bit from this, all works, i have modified slightly as i decided to pull in values  for each post as well, so my block looks like this <% @toppost.each do |k, v| %> so that i had access to the keys and values...thanks again :)